# Angular app fails to match route on query param

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have an Angular 14 application which by default load as

```
https://abc/checkout/index.html
```

but at sometimes I get the URL as

```
https://abc/checkout/index.html?isAddrPassedFromVSI=false&token=EC-7F3328316X938605Y&PayerID=3G93VFQNSW3PL
```

My route config is as follows,

```
routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: CheckoutComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'checkout',
    component: CheckoutComponent,
  },
]
```

On second URL with query param, which I can ignore I`m getting an error and page doesn`t load

[image],

Please help what should I fix here

Comment: Interesting. Have you tried adding a catch all route to redirect to the CheckoutComponent? The path would be `**`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/checkout', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'checkout',component: CheckoutComponent}
]
```

Comment: will it remove the query params??